# Django Not matching URL, No Reverse Match

Tags: python, django

I'm using a TDD based approach to my Django project, which is a database of homebrew materials. I've been able to add a hops record with passing functional and unit tests. The issue I'm having is with the update view function (editing an existing record). I've done this before with class based views and ran into some errors that I couldn't back out of which is why I'm using the TDD/function view approach instead of going straight to CBV's.

I'm currently getting the following error indicating that there's no reverse match for my view `beerdb/edit/(?P<pk>\\d+)/hops/$`. So I created a get_absolute_url method on my Hop model:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('updatehops', kwargs={'pk': self.id})
```

to return that reverse url:

```
django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'updatehops' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['beerdb/edit/(?P<pk>\\d+)/hops/$']
```

Here is my test, the result of which is the error above:

```
    def test_can_update_hops(self):
        self.client.post(
            '/beerdb/add/hops/',
            data={
                'name': 'Warrior',
                'min_alpha_acid': 24.00,
                'max_alpha_acid': 32.00,
                'country': 'USA',
                'comments': 'Very bitter, not good for aroma'
            })

        hop_instance = Hop.objects.filter(name='Warrior')[0]
        response = self.client.get('/beerdb/edit/%d/hops/' % hop_instance.id)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

My other project details are below. Can anyone point out where I might be going wrong? I also think my urls.py might need some revision. I can't quite figure out how to return the reversed url with the template. I've looked over the render, render_to_response, redirect and HttpResponseRedirect objects but I don't see how to return that context. In a class based view, I would call the super method and get the context data, adding the primary key to 'action', but I don't know how I can apply that here.

**Project Details**

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.homebrewmain, name='beerdb_main'),
    url(r'^hops/$', views.hops, name='hops_list'),
    url(r'^add/hops/$', views.addhops, name='addhops'),
    url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/hops/$', views.updatehops, name='updatehops')
]
```

models.py

```
class Hop(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    min_alpha_acid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    max_alpha_acid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)

    # Country codes for origin (as defined by http://countrycode.org)
    AUSTRALIA = 'AUS'
    CANADA = 'CAN'
    CHINA = 'CHN'
    CZECH_REPUBLIC = 'CZE'
    FRANCE = 'FRA'
    GERMANY = 'DEU'
    NEW_ZEALAND = 'NZL'
    POLAND = 'POL'
    UNITED_KINGDOM = 'GBR'
    UNITED_STATES = 'USA'

    COUNTRY_CODES = (
        (AUSTRALIA, 'Australia'),
        (CANADA, 'Canada'),
        (CHINA, 'China'),
        (CZECH_REPUBLIC, 'Czech Republic'),
        (FRANCE, 'France'),
        (GERMANY, 'Germany'),
        (NEW_ZEALAND, 'New Zealand'),
        (POLAND, 'Poland'),
        (UNITED_KINGDOM, 'United Kingdom'),
        (UNITED_STATES, 'United States'),
    )

    country = models.CharField(max_length=3,
                               choices=COUNTRY_CODES,
                               default=UNITED_STATES
                               )

    comments = models.TextField(default='')
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('updatehops', kwargs={'pk': self.id})
```

**Edit:** I've updated my view function to return a redirect of the reverse url without the dot notation:

```
def updatehops(request, pk):

    hop_record = Hop.objects.filter(pk=pk)[0]
    edit_form = HopForm(request.POST or None, instance=hop_record)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if edit_form.is_valid():
            edit_form.save()
            success_url = reverse('hops_list')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
    hop_form_url = reverse('updatehops', kwargs={'pk': hop_record.id})
    return redirect(hop_form_url)
```

As noted in my comments below, this gets the test to pass if I assert status_code on the response = 302, but I need 200 to make sure I'm getting the rendered form so I can access the content in the response, change some of the data and resave when I write the rest of the test later.

**Update:** I've amended the url after doing some research so that it now passes in the hop_id instead of `<pk>`:

```
url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/hops/$', views.updatehops, name='updatehops'),
```

I'm still getting the error, but it's received the pk in the error message:

```
django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'updatehops' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 7}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['beerdb/edit/(?P<hop_id>\\d+)/hops/$']
```

**Edit 2: I've added 'pk' back to the URL, adding traceback**

*Traceback*

```
Template error:
In template /Path/To/Site/Site/homebrewdatabase/templates/homebrewdatabase/hops.html, error at line 23
   Reverse for 'updatehops' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['beerdb/edit/(?P<pk>\\d+)/hops/$']   
   13 :         {% include 'homebrewdatabase/addhops.html' %}
   14 : 
   15 :         <!--Modal data begins here to edit hops-->
   16 :         <div class="modal fade" id="updatehops" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
   17 :             <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   18 :                <div class="modal-content">
   19 :                    <div class="modal-header">
   20 :                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
   21 :                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Hops</h4>
   22 :               </div>
   23 :               <form action=" {% url 'homebrewdatabase:updatehops' pk=hop.id %} " method="POST">
   24 :                 <div class="modal-body">
   25 :                     {{ form.as_p }}
   26 :                     {%  csrf_token %}
   27 :                 </div>
   28 :               <div class="modal-footer">
   29 :                 <button type="button" id="close" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   30 :                 <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
   31 :               </form>
   32 :               </div>
   33 :             </div>
```

**Edit 3:** [views.py](http://pastebin.com/ksKQzbnM) and [hops.html](http://pastebin.com/vRJSFA2f)

Comment: The `reverse` function (as well as the `url` tag in templates) takes the name that you give it in urls, not the dotted module path of the view. Namespaces are separated by colons (`:`).

Comment: I've updated the first parameter to the view function, but then I have to redirect to the reverse view, which gets the test to pass if I'm asserting the response status code is 302, but I'm trying to get 200. At that point, I'm stuck with an HttpResponseRedirect object that has not content, so I can't edit the form when I right the rest of the test.

Comment: @Sandwhich Heat Well, what's in your view. If it returns a redirect response, 301/302/etc will be the status codes you'll get... and should expect.

Comment: Agreed. I can't figure out how to return the reverse url in my view with the template rendered using the form as context. The view definitely needs to be fixed, I'm just not sure how.

Comment: The problem in the template is `hop.id` in the url tag. Are you sure you passed `hop` when rendering the template.  You haven't shown that part of your view.

Comment: Yes, I've passed them in. In my hops.html template, I was able to iterate over each hop using {% for hop in hops %} before. I've added an Edit 3 with pastebin links to my full views.py and hops.html files.

Comment: You are using `hop.id` outside of your loop through `hops`. Therefore, `hop.id` evaluates to an empty string, and the URL tag gives an error.

Comment: What's the correct way to pass that to the action attribute?

Comment: To rephrase that, in a CBV, I'd normally give the view the template, the form, override get context data and amend context['action']. Then I would pass it to the template in an {{ action }} attribute where I'm currently getting the error. What is the function view equivalent of the {{ action }} url?

Comment: Include it in the dictionary that you pass to render: `render(request, 'homebrewdatabase/hops.html', {'hops': hops_list, 'form': HopForm(), 'action': '/action/url/'})`.

Comment: Ah, I see. So I can call reverse on the url with the hop id and then pass that as the action link into the template. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the test client to follow the redirect, use `follow=True`.

```
response = self.client.post(
        '/beerdb/add/hops/',
        data={...}, 
        follow=True, 
   )
```

You can then check the content of the response. If you then want to test the redirect, you can use [`assertRedirects`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertRedirects) instead of checking the status code.

Here's a couple of tips about reversing urls. Firstly, use the url pattern name, eg `updatehops`, instead of the full path to the view, `'homebrewdatabase.views.updatehop'`. Secondly, make sure your kwargs match. You have `hop_id` in the url. Therefore you need

```
reverse('updatehops', kwargs={'hop_id': hop_record.id})
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a good catch, it doesn't quite solve the issue, but I'll post my traceback up here. I hope this will help.

Comment: I also should have mentioned that I've already updated the get_absolute_url with `return reverse('updatehops', kwargs={'pk': self.id})`. I've posted the traceback (I added namespacing).

Comment: I'm selecting this answer, adding a few points. get_absolute_url was not needed. A link pointing to a modal that I had put back in the page to debug, but I had the actual modal in a file called updatehops.html. The view was rendering the updatehops.html file, but I hadn't update the form url to {{ action }} there, instead it was the wrong url that I had been using before, the url tag. I didn't need to focus on returning a reverse URL, Django just couldn't find it because it wasn't getting the right action. The modal isn't popping up, but that issue is out of scope for this post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
response = self.client.get('/beerdb/edit/%d/hops/' % hop_instance.id)
```

Shouldn't above line be as beerdb_main instead of just beerdb in the above line of your test code.

FYI: I am referring to test section of your code.

Comment: Hmm, I see where you mean, but I'm not sure how this would fit as the '/beerdb' url looks correct in my project urls.py file. I'm confident the test is written correctly. However, I also think I need to look at the url I wrote. It doesn't appear to be matching.

Comment: you urls do not have 'beerdb', it has only 'beerdb_main'
can you please try the below line once?

response = self.client.get('/beerdb_main/edit/%d/hops/' % hop_instance.id)

Answer (score -1):

You have to do it such:
`reverse('updatehops')`

Check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/urlresolvers/